# how to autoscale node kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling

as We know we can autoscale on pods so here actually I have 2 question:
1. How to autoscaling nodes on kubernetes ?
2. How to trigger autoscaling group with AWS ?

Comment: AFAIK there is currently no way to do this on AWS, but it is targeted for v1.3 - see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11935. This is possible on GCE - see http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/cluster-management/#horizontal-auto-scaling-of-nodes-gce.

Comment: First of, Thx for the answer about the issues.
and I looking forward for v1.3 
hope it is coming very soon :D

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the AWS ASG in the web console and select the minion ASG

example: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/home?region=us-west-2#AutoScalingGroups:id=kubernetes-dev-minion-group-us-west-2a;view=details

Then edit the ASG's min,max you should get more/less nodes:

[adjusting the num nodes in ASG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2dUH.png)

Comment: If you increase the min or desired so new nodes will come online, will those nodes auto register themselves with the cluster?

Comment: If you used kube-up, then yes. They will bootstrap from the salt files stored in S3 and register with the cluster.